# How to use Leaflet to create a map out of an image

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

OK, I have found an example of exactly what I think I require. I cannot work out how to set it up for my image and I'm not sure if this is the best approach to achieve my goal.

**Intended Result :**

http://maps.mixedbredie.net/leaflet/image.html

**Example Code:**

```
var map = L.map('map', {maxZoom: 17}).setView([51.495, -0.075], 14);
        /* Instead of a tile layer, use a bitmap image */
        var imageUrl = 'data/TM_pano.jpg';
        var imageBounds = [[51.490, -0.122], [51.510, -0.028]];
        L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
        L.marker([51.495, -0.075]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("This is Table Mountain.");
        var popup = L.popup();
        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(map);
        }
        map.on('click', onMapClick);
        map.setMaxBounds(imageBounds);
```

**Questions:**

**1.)** How to choose the longitude/latitude, image bounds?

- i.e. .setView([51.495, -0.075], 14)
- var imageBounds = [[51.490, -0.122], [51.510, -0.028]];

**2.)** Should zoom 0 show my whole image? What are reasonable limits?

**3.)** Can I use real coordinates with this approach? i.e. Mapping a water pipe underground but using a custom .jpg of that pipe schematic? Then I could put markers on the pipe for certain long/lats.

Answer (score 1):

See http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/ for question 1 and 2
For the third one, you could georeference (or warp) the image, and then display it onto a map, setting the transparency for example.
The georeferencing could be done with Qgis or a tool like Mapwarper https://github.com/timwaters/mapwarper

(old question, but I think an answer could be useful)

Comment: Hmm doesent seem to work with svg images

Answer (score 0):

You might also be looking for

https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/blob/gh-pages/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated.js

Demo url

http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/demo.html

Sadly if there is a non linear projection more advanced is still needed.

But ofthen i think this might be close enough